# matlab code for image cropping without using inbuilt function

Tags: matlab, crop

The below code is for cropping the excess white part of an image.(for the purpose of reducing the image size ). i.e. if **"A"** is present in the image then all the excess white portion at the top ,bottom, left and right would be removed.

In this code i am not able to understand the use of **"sum"** function,please help in that..

```
 %  Find the boundary of the image
  [y2temp x2temp] = size(bw);
 x1=1;
 y1=1; 
  x2=x2temp; 
  y2=y2temp;


 % Finding left side blank spac es
 cntB=1;
 while (sum(bw(:,cntB))==y2temp)
  x1=x1+1;
 cntB=cntB+1;
    end


  % Finding right side blank spaces
 cntB=1;
  while (sum(bw(cntB,:))==x2temp)
 y1=y1+1;
 cntB=cntB+1;
end


 % Finding upper side blank spaces
cntB=x2temp;
 while (sum(bw(:,cntB))==y2temp)
x2=x2-1;
cntB=cntB-1;
end


 %  Finding lower side blank spaces
 cntB=y2temp;
 while (sum(bw(cntB,:))==x2temp)  
 y2=y2-1;
 cntB=cntB-1;  
 end


 % Crop the image to the edge
  bw2=imcrop(bw,[x1,y1,(x2-x1),(y2-y1)]);
```

Comment: Read the [](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html)

Comment: in addition. Here it sums over a row or column of the image `bw`. The index is called `cntB`. If they are all ones then the sum is equal to the total length. So it continues the while loop.

Comment: thanks ,i understood the code.

Answer (score 0):

This code probably does the same thing, in less lines.

```
bw_bin=bw==1; %make it binary
row = all(bw_bin); %checks if they are all one
column = all(bw_bin');
bw=bw(find(column==0,1,'first'):find(column==0,1,'last'),find(row==0,1,'first'):find(row==0,1,'last')); %ake only the rows and columns where this is not the case
```